# React Native 0.64 - Make password manager suggest password for app

Tags: android, ios, react-native, mobile, passwords

I have the following problem:
I have got a React Native application with login feature. The current way it works is that upon login the user has to scroll till they find their login for an app in password manager.

Is it possible to make password manager suggest password for the app, i.e. the app password be at the top of the passwords list when opening from this app?
Also, is there a way to connect an app and a website, so that if user has no password for the app, password manager will suggest him password for concrete website?

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `autocomplete` field

https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#autocomplete-android